# How to find and select every occurences of specific word in Memo?

Tags: delphi, text, replace, tmemo

I am making application which replaces different words of two very similar speaking languages. Number of words by time will probably reach at least 10.000+. There is no big differences in words, it is almost same languages, but however differences exists.

So, I managed to replace words in Memo fast enough, but what I dont know is how to select all replaced words in Memo so it can be seen which words are replaced. Is this possible?

This is how words are replaced:

```
procedure TForm1.TranslateExecute(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
    S, OldPattern, NewPattern: string;
begin
  S:= Memo1.Lines.Text;

  for i := 0 to (StrListV.Count - 1) do  {StrListV is created earlier, contains words that should be replaced}
  begin        
    OldPattern:= StrListV.Strings[i];
    NewPattern:= StrListV1.Strings[i]; {StrListV1 contains new words}
    S:= FastStringReplace(S, OldPattern, NewPattern,[rfReplaceAll]);
  end;

  Memo1.BeginUpdate;
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:= S;
  Memo1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: Edit controls can have only one selection. I guess you are looking for a way to highlight the text, not select. If so, you can use rich edit control for that.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to to highlight text.

Comment: Perhaps a third party edit control is what you need

Comment: For instance common rich edit control (`TRichEdit`) can do that, but you will need to locate where each word to be highlighted is in the control's content to highlight it (naturally, a simple content string replace is not enough for your overall task).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `TMemo` or `TRichEdit` support multiple selections, so you cannot actually highlight the words that have been replaced.  But with `TRichEdit`, what you CAN do is change the foreground/background colors of the words you replace.

`TRichEdit` has a `FindText()` method (which wraps the `EM_FINDTEXT` message) that returns the index of a search string.  Call it in a loop, and or each found word you can select it, set its coloring, and replace it with the new text.  Repeat until `FindText()` does not find any more matches.

Try something like this:

```
uses
  RichEdit, CommDlg;

procedure TForm1.TranslateExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, Pos: Integer;
  EventMask: LRESULT;
  OldPattern, NewPattern: string;
  Find: RichEdit.FINDTEXT;
  Rng: RichEdit.CHARRANGE;
  Fmt: RichEdit.CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  EventMask := SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to StrListV.Count - 1 do
    begin        
      OldPattern := StrListV.Strings[I];
      NewPattern := StrListV1.Strings[I];
      Pos := 0;
      repeat
        Find.chrg.cpMin := Pos;
        Find.chrg.cpMax := -1;
        Find.lpstrText := PChar(OldPattern);
        Pos := SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_FINDTEXT, FR_DOWN or FR_WHOLEWORD, LPARAM(@Find));
        if Pos = -1 then Break;

        Rng.cpMin := Pos;
        Rng.cpMax := Pos + Length(OldPattern);

        ZeroMemory(@Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt));
        Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
        Fmt.dwMask := CFM_COLOR or CFM_BACKCOLOR;
        Fmt.crTextColor := ColorToRGB(clHighlightText);
        Fmt.crBackColor := ColorToRGB(clHighlight);

        SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@Rng));
        SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));
        SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, LPARAM(PChar(NewPattern)));

        Inc(Pos, Length(NewPattern));
      until False;
    end;
  finally
    RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, EventMask);
  end;
end;
```